# How to tell if string is null or empty in meta value?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

I am trying to figure out how to find make sure a string is not null or empty then execute code. The place I am pulling the value from is a meta value that is stored from a meta box on the post page in wordpress.

I want to check if this returns a null or empty value and if it doesnt then execute code after:

```
<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'newtheme_section_id', true) ); ?>
```

The code above retrieves a value that the user had input into a meta box on the post page.

I was thinking that I would remove the echo and create a variable to hold the output of get_post_meta then somehow check if the variable is null or empty.

I had actually posted it in the Wordpress Stack Exchange website but it was more of a php question so I posted it here.

Comment: Create your own function to check if the variable pushed through it is `empty` or `isset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if its empty with one of these functions

```
isset($var)
```

This returns TRUE is the variable is set.

or with this

```
empty($var)
```

This returns TRUE is the variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this while using the WP Types & Fields plugin from Toolset.

`isset($var)` didn't work correctly. Even empty fields returned true.

`empty($var)` did work correctly.

You could also test the string's length.